# Rails reload will cause devise to error out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm experiencing the below spurious error whenever I reload my rails server, or rails console.

Everything works fine if i do not edit code on the fly that causes rails server to reload, or if i do not trigger the reload! command manually on rails console.

Any ideas will be most appreciated!

```
 2.1.5 :006 > reload!
    Reloading...
    RuntimeError: User does not respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'
        from /Users/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@Googl/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:490:in `raise_no_devise_method_error!'
        from /Users/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@Googl/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:227:in `block in devise_for'
        from /Users/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@Googl/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
        from /Users/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@Googl/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
        from /Users/v/workspace/Googl/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

To prevent clutter, the
application.rb / user model file can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd024a796264d638f755

Comment: can you paste you initializer applciation.rb and the User model please

Comment: sure. ive updated the question to include them. I cant show the entire User model due to some propietary code too.